# Cannot change the colour of HTML element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, console, background-color, getelementsbyclassname

It's a very simple line of code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("header-2014 clearfix")[0].backgroundColor = "#FF0000"
```

I'm trying to use it here:

http://www.roblox.com/Chess-place?id=95041893

I'm using the JavaScript console (could that have anything to do with it?)

I'm expecting a very simple answer, so help would be appreciated, it's probably just some simple syntax error that a newbie to JavaScript (like me) would have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously want to change the [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style) of the element, so don't forget to mention it in the code:

```
... [0].style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
```

Comment: Ooh Thanks, I'll be back to upvote/mark best answer later if it works.

Comment: Thanks for saving me the time ;D it won't let me say @VisioN